# ASP.net LoginStatus - change status to logout when log in successful

Tags: asp.net

How should I go about this? I mean how does the control know whether someone is logged in or not? Session ID? Cookies?

Recommendation of which one I should implement? A guide or tutorial would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's shown in the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228140.aspx

> **Remarks**
>   The LoginStatus control has
>   two states:
>
> Logged on to the Web site.
>
> Logged off from the Web site.
>
> The state is determined by the
>   IsAuthenticated property of the
>   Request property.
>
> For more information about using the
>   LoginStatus control and other login
>   controls, see ASP.NET Login Controls
>   Overview

```
<asp:LoginStatus id="LoginStatus1" loginText="Log In"
             logoutAction="Refresh"  logoutText="Log Out"
             runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your scenario whether you are allowed to use cookies or not.
If there are no special requirements the standard Membership provider would be a good start. Out-of-the-box it uses cookies to store the authentication token.

This link gives you an idea: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91f66yxt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if a user is logged in or not you can use:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The LoginStatus control just reads the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property to decide what to display.  Here's a [quick one-pager](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3655706/ASPNET-Tip-Using-the-LoginName-and-LoginStatus-Controls.htm) on how to use it.

You should probably read up on Forms Authentication in ASP.Net, and how it handles session and user cookies to deal with authentication.